# Two Spreadsheets, Merge Data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, merge, sorting

I was wondering what is the best way to merge two spreadsheets which have the name id's e.g:

One sheet has:

```
apple   5
dog     3
cat     2
```

Second sheet:

```
dog     4
apple   7
cat     3
```

I would like to merge the two so that I have

```
apple   5    7
dog     4    3
cat     2    3
```

They're not in order, and sorting them in Excel didn't help to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is easiest done in a database using [Joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29), but you can do it in excel using VLOOKUP.

First create a third sheet, and paste the 'dog, cat, etc' columns from sheet one and two into a single column in sheet 3. The use Excel 2007's [Remove Duplicates](http://helpdeskgeek.com/office-tips/excel-remove-duplicates/) feature to remove duplicates.

Then in the second column, specify the formula =VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!A$1:B$100, 2, false) where A1 is the cell to the left of the cell youu're editing (on sheet 3) and A1:B100 is the region on sheet 1 containing data.

In the third column you specify a similar formula, but pointing to Sheet 2, =VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet2!A$1:B$100, 2, false).

You may need to sort the data in sheet 1 and 2, and the names on sheet 3.

Comment: If you’re using an Excel version before 2007 "Remove Duplicates" is not available, but you can achieve the same effect from the `Data` -> `Filter` -> `Advanced Filter` control by getting it to copying to a new location and ticking "Unique records only".